# How can I specify optional request parameters for a Grails command object?

Tags: validation, grails, groovy

**UPDATE:** code changed to make it look Groovier XD

Like the title says. Suppose I have a command object:

```
@Validateable
class MyCommand {
    String myProperty1
    String myProperty2
    String myProperty3
    static constraints = {
        myProperty1(blank: false)
    }
}
```

And I also have a controller which tries to populate a new instance of my command object upon receiving a `GET` request:

```
class HeyController {
    def doSomething(MyCommand mc) {
        render [result: mc] as JSON
    }
}
```

Note that I only want to make `myProperty1` a required parameter in this example (i.e. I'd like `myProperty2` and `myProperty3` to be optional request parameters). However, if I throw in this request:

```
http://myappserver:8080/app/hey/doSomething?myProperty1=foo
```

Grails will still complain that `myProperty2` and `myProperty3` have `null` values.

So, what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Grails? If 2.4.*, then you have to specifically specify constraints as `nullable: true` for prop2 and prop3 because they are false by default in command objects alike domain classes.

Comment: @dmahapatro does it make any difference? I think `nullable: true` has been around since....forever

Comment: @Dónal Yes it does. See my updated comment. This default behavior was added recently.

Comment: Ah, yes... nullable. *head desk*, just found it in the documentation. I need more coffee :P. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't directly related to your question but a couple of things about your code... The action method should not be declared to return `JSON`.  You should declare all controller actions as public methods which return `Object`.  The usual way to do that is with something like `def doSomething() { ... }`.  (the rest is too long to fit in one comment, second comment comming...)

Comment: Also, instead of doing `MyCommandObject mco = new MyCommandObject(params); mco.validate()` inside of your controller action you can just declare the action with something like `def doSometing(MyCommandObject mco) { ... }` and Grails will take care of creating the instance, doing data binding on it with params and calling `.validate()` all before your controller action ever gets executed.

Comment: And finally....don't append `Object` to the name of your command class, it's not an object, it's a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Validateable
class MyCommandObject {
    String myProperty1
    String myProperty2
    String myProperty3


    static constraints = {

        myProperty2 nullable: true
        myProperty3 nullable: true
    }
}
```